# Fix stuck AWS Elasticsearch upgrade (5.6 -> 6.8)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I initiated an upgrade from Elasticsearch 5.6 to 6.8 on AWS last weekend, but after completing 55% of the upgrade it seems to have gotten stuck (>24h at 55%). The old service is still operational.

I would like to understand what my options are at this point. I do NOT have a manual snapshot, but I do have an automated snapshot. No writes happened, so the snapshot should be up to date.

With a manual snapshot I could simple launch a new instance, restore the old snapshot and point my services to the new instance. This is unfortunately not possible with an automated snapshot.

I'm reluctant to restart the service mid-upgrade as I do not know if it'll come back up and, if it does, in what state. In fact, the only action offered right now is 'delete domain', which might or might not delete the automated snapshot as well.

Any Elasticsearch experts care to suggest the best way forward to restore the service with least risk and minimal downtime?

Answer (score 1):

Engage AWS Elasticsearch support to find out why the upgrade i stuck and fix it.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have paid support... and there is no (official) way to raise a bug with an AWS service without paid support. In the end I raised an account/billing service request and the relayed the issue to the Elasticsearch team who fixed it (without explaining the root cause).